# Solving a set of equations: $\frac{7}{x+y}+xy=-7$ and $\frac{y}{y+1}+\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{xy+x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Solve a set of equations
$\frac{7}{x+y}+xy=-7$ and $\frac{y}{y+1}+\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{xy+x}$

I stumbled on this problem in my text book and I am having trouble dealing with starting to solve it and I'm not to sure where to start, personally   this is far above my level of understanding.

All I really need is some help on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Start from the 2nd equation by adding the terms and cancelling the common terms..

Comment: Adding the two together would give me $\frac{yx+y+1}{x(y+1)}$

Comment: Yes and then you can cancel the denominator and you will be left with a relation between x and y which you can use in eqn . 1

Comment: That would then leave me with yx + y + 1 = 1 which then can be simplified to yx + y = 0 then into yx = -y then divide by y giving me x = -1

Comment: Also, $y=0$....

Comment: Then input -1 for x in the first equation giving me $\frac{7}{(-1)+y}+(-1)y=-7$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the second equation,

$$\frac{y}{y+1} +\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{xy+x}$$

$$\frac{yx+y+1}{x(y+1)} = \frac{1}{xy+x}$$
Cancellation of the denominator terms gives
$$yx+y=(x+1)y=0$$ so that

**CASE 1** y=0. This is trivial wrt the second equation of the original system, as putting it in the second equation gives $\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{x}$. But putting y=0 in the first equation of the original system gives x = —1 which implies that (—1,0) is a solution.

**CASE 2** x+1=0 or $x = -1$.

Using x=-1 in the first equation of the original system gives$\frac{7}{y-1}-y=-7$, rearranging which gives $\frac{7}{y-1}+7=y$, or $\frac{7y}{y-1}=y$, of which y=0 is automatically a solution. If y≠0, then $y=8$ and $x=-1$ so (—1,8) is another solution.

 The two solutions two the system are $(-1,0)$ and $(-1,8)$.

Comment: This is exactly what I asked for so thanks for helping me out.

Comment: You’re welcome :)